# Update tls secret for Ambassador

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, ambassador

I need to apply certificate in the solution after the solution has been deployed.As ambassador listen to the change in tls secret I took this approach.After my application has been deployed my ambassador uses a default self signed certificate.I updated that certificate with this command

```
kubectl create secret tls ambassador-tls-secret \
     --cert=/root/tls.crt --key=/root/tls.key  --dry-run -o yaml | 
  kubectl apply -f -
```

My secret has now been updated but my Ambassador still doesnt listen to the new secret.
Is there something wrong with the way I have updated my secret ?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Ambassador to terminate TLS with either a `TLSContext` or tls `Module` resource. To get either to simply terminate TLS using the secret you created, you can configure them like

tls `Module`:

```
---
apiVersion: ambassador/v1
kind: Module
name: tls
config:
  server:
    enabled: true
    secret: ambassador-tls-secret
```

`TLSContext`:

```
---
apiVersion: ambassador/v1
kind: TLSContext
name: ambassador
secret: ambassador-tls-secret
hosts: ["*"]
```

After configuring either of these, Ambassador should notice the `ambassador-tls-secret` you created and use the certificates for tls termination.

You can verify Ambassador has been configured correctly by checking the `envoy.json` configuration file in the Ambassador container

```
kubectl exec -it {AMBASSADOR_POD_NAME} -- cat envoy/envoy.json
```

If Ambassador has been correctly configured, you should see an Envoy `tls_context` configured and the listener named `ambassador-listener-8443` like below:

```
                        "tls_context": {
                            "common_tls_context": {
                                "tls_certificates": [
                                    {
                                        "certificate_chain": {
                                            "filename": "/ambassador/snapshots/default/secrets-decoded/ambassador-certs/66877DCC8C7B7AF190D3510AE5B4BFC71FADB308.crt"
                                        },
                                        "private_key": {
                                            "filename": "/ambassador/snapshots/default/secrets-decoded/ambassador-certs/66877DCC8C7B7AF190D3510AE5B4BFC71FADB308.key"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "use_proxy_proto": false
                    }
                ],
                "name": "ambassador-listener-8443"
```

If you do not, then Ambassador has rejected your config for some reason. Check the logs of the Ambassador container, ensure you have only a tls `Module` **or** `TLSContext` configured, check to see if `service_port` has been configured in an [ambassador Module](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/core/ambassador), and ensure you have the correct [ambassador_id](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/running#ambassador_id).

Comment: I have configured tls module.
But `kubectl exec -it {AMBASSADOR_POD_NAME} -- cat envoy/envoy.json ` doesnt give me tls_context in my envoy.json.

Comment: Then it is probable Ambassador has either thrown out your config or not seen it for some reason. Check the logs from the Ambassador pod for any errors and check to make sure you have `ambassador_id` configure correctly. Also make sure you are creating the secret in the same namespace as Ambassador.

Comment: @NoahKrause I am also not seeing the tls_context in my envoy.json. I saw the error as secret mysecret.ambassador unknow. But I am having secret in my configuration. I am able to see my secret using kubectl get command. I also configured the correct name sapce.